# Error en MainActivity.java - R : Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27

Tags: android-studio

package com.example.diseo.ejemplo1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

### }

ERROR: 10:32 AM Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: C:\Android\Sdk

### Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (618ms)

BUILD GRADE:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.diseo.ejemplo1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

[image: ERROR EN R MAINACTIVITY.JAVA]

Answer (score 0):

El problema

> Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string
>   'android-27' in

indica que no tienes la versión 27 del SDK instalada por esta razón no puede construirse tu proyecto, ve a `SDK Manager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona la versión 27 y da clic en "apply":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma se realizará la instalación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tenia esta etiqueta del Manifest que daba ese error, que era de un ejemplo de search diccionary
 `<uses-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "15" android: targetSdkVersion = "27" />`, Luego la borre y sincronice y funciono bien. Luego actualize esa etiqueta como deberia ir

```
    <uses-sdk android: minSdkVersion = "15" android: targetSdkVersion = "27" />
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], por favor traduce tu respuesta :)